# vim macro not recording movement commands at the end

Tags: vim

I have a block of text something like following -

```
blah blah 1 blah blah
blah 1 blah 1 blah
```

I want to copy it n number of times but increment the integer (1 above) each time I paste. Something like -

```
blah blah 1 blah blah
blah 1 blah 1 blah

blah blah 2 blah blah
blah 2 blah 2 blah

blah blah 3 blah blah
blah 3 blah 3 blah
```

I put the cursor at the start of the block and start recording a macro in reg a with 'qa'
and type 'y2jp<kbd>^A</kbd>j0<kbd>^A</kbd>w<kbd>^A</kbd>k0'. In english - copy and paste the block, increment each number and go back to the beginning of the newly pasted block so that the macro can be run again.

Everything works fine except the 'k0' part at the end, it doesn't move the cursor to the beginning of the newly pasted block. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

@sehe I get following when I run the macro suggested by you -

blah blah 1 blah blah
blah 1 blah 1 blah
blah blah 1 blah blahj0.w.yk0
blah 1 blah 1 blah

Looks like vim is still in insert mode after ^A.
:-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are better ways to achieve what you are doing, and I haven't actually looked at the details of what is going wrong for you, just here is a macro that works for me:

> 2Yjp<kbd>^A</kbd>j0.w.yk0

I think you were doing the things in reverse (inserting at the top?) - the problem *might* have been that the cursor couldn't move up before the first line (? haven't tested).

Anyways, after `20@a` I get:

```
blah blah 1 blah blah
blah 1 blah 1 blah
blah blah 2 blah blah
blah 2 blah 2 blah
blah blah 3 blah blah
blah 3 blah 3 blah
blah blah 4 blah blah
blah 4 blah 4 blah
blah blah 5 blah blah
blah 5 blah 5 blah
blah blah 6 blah blah
blah 6 blah 6 blah
blah blah 7 blah blah
blah 7 blah 7 blah
blah blah 8 blah blah
blah 8 blah 8 blah
blah blah 9 blah blah
blah 9 blah 9 blah
blah blah 10 blah blah
blah 10 blah 10 blah
blah blah 11 blah blah
blah 11 blah 11 blah
blah blah 12 blah blah
blah 12 blah 12 blah
blah blah 13 blah blah
blah 13 blah 13 blah
blah blah 14 blah blah
blah 14 blah 14 blah
blah blah 15 blah blah
blah 15 blah 15 blah
blah blah 16 blah blah
blah 16 blah 16 blah
blah blah 17 blah blah
blah 17 blah 17 blah
blah blah 18 blah blah
blah 18 blah 18 blah
blah blah 19 blah blah
blah 19 blah 19 blah
blah blah 20 blah blah
blah 20 blah 20 blah
blah blah 21 blah blah
blah 21 blah 21 blah
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is going wrong with your use of `k0`, but to get the cursor to go back, you may find it easier to use a mark instead. For example:

> 2Yjpma<kbd>^A</kbd>j0<kbd>^A</kbd>w<kbd>^A</kbd>`a

Comment: again the text j0^AW^A`a is shown after the first line of the pasted text.

Comment: @Raminder: Could it be that you are copy/pasting the macro and getting "^" and "A" as separate characters instead of Ctrl-a? Then the "A" would put you into insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
p
:,+2s/\d\+/\=1+submatch(0)/g "replaces digits by 1+value on all occurences till line + 2
:-2,y "yanks from line - 2 till current line (=last line with replacement)
```

?